# LightSwitch Desktop Application Installation failing: "Strong name signature not valid for this assembly vslshost.exe"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've created a LighSwitch desktop application in Visual Studio 2013 which installs perfectly fine on my development machine but fails during installation on my client's machine with the following error message:

Strong name signature not valid for this assembly vslshost.exe

I found a similar issue that was also raised on the MSDN forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28736d83-db94-4d0b-adb9-2ff2e6d0ba95/installation-failing-strong-name-signature-not-valid-for-this-assembly-vslshostexe?forum=lightswitch

One person replied stating that other people have previously given solutions to this error but neither I nor the original poster could find these solutions.

I've followed the How to: Deploy a Two-tier LightSwitch Application guide found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff852056.aspx

However, the problem persists for my client but not for me.

Can anyone help with this?

Here are some details from the error log:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.1022
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.245 (RTMGDR.030319-2400)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.1022 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : [APPLICATION], Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : [APPLICATION_EXE], Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of [APPLICATION] resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Strong name signature not valid for this assembly vslshost.exe.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The file named default.htm does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.
    * The file named web.config does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [25/02/2014 8:11:42 AM] : Activation of [APPLICATION] has started.
    * [25/02/2014 8:11:42 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [25/02/2014 8:11:42 AM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [25/02/2014 8:11:42 AM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [25/02/2014 8:11:45 AM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [25/02/2014 8:11:45 AM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [25/02/2014 8:11:46 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
        - Strong name signature not valid for this assembly vslshost.exe.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyStrongNameAssembly(String filePath, AssemblyManifest assemblyManifest)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.StrongNameAssemblyComponent.Verify()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyComponents()
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if further information would be useful in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Is no one able to help me with this?

Comment: I found that http://stackoverflow.com/a/25031628/434832 works for me, maybe that's similar issue.