# Strong name signature not valid for this assembly Microsoft.LightSwitch.Model.Xaml.dll

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I deployed a desktop lightswitch application and my users are getting this error when they install the application:

```
Strong name signature not valid for this assembly Microsoft.LightSwitch.Model.Xaml.dll
```

This error is causing the install to fail.  Does anyone know the cause of this error or where to start looking?

Answer (score 0):

What happened in my case is that VS 2013 has upgraded my LightSwitch app to .net 4.5 framework. The app works ok on machines with .net 4.5 but on machines with 4.0 I get the exact same error during installation process. You can either downgrade the app to .net 4.0 or ask users to install .net 4.5.

Comment: thanks.  i thought i installed 4.5 on the target machine that was receiving this error but i will try again.